# Jquery - Adding class every 500 milliseconds

Tags: jquery, loops, addclass

What I'm trying to do is use jQuery to add a class every 500 milliseconds to every "li" element that is located inside a "ul" with an ID of #menu-offcanvas.

I can set all the ID's at once obviously with this

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#menu-offcanvas li').addClass('myclass');
},500);
```

But what I need it to do is loop through those "li" elements and add that class immediately to the first one and then every 500 milliseconds to the following "li" elements.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you provide a real world example of this in use so I can have a better understanding of what is actually happening besides applying a style every x seconds to a random element

Comment: @kepoly...Why? Everyone else understood. Plus the elements are not random...

Comment: It would help me work out a solution a lot easier for you... ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var timeDif = 0;
$($('#menu-offcanvas li').get().reverse()).each(function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $el.addClass('myclass');
    },500 * timeDif);
    timeDif++;
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/toby3105/5cmb6257/2/) is a working example

Comment: Chaged this one to my accepted answer. This works beautiful.

Comment: How can I make this loop start with the last "li" element?

Comment: @agon024 Updated the answer and the fiddle

Comment: Oh my god.....get().reverse()....I should have known that. I'm still new to jquery so I forget native functions some time. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try utilizing `.queue()`

```js
var menu = $("#menu-offcanvas");

menu.queue("addClass", $.map(menu.find("li"), function(el, i) {
  return function(next) {
    $(el).addClass("myclass");
    setTimeout(function() {
      next()
    }, 500)
  }
})).dequeue("addClass");
```

```css
.myclass {
  background: skyblue;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-offcanvas">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
  <li>g</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

use as function:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
    if($('#menu-offcanvas li:not(.myclass)').first().length) {
        $('#menu-offcanvas li:not(.myclass)').first().addClass('myclass');
    } else clearInterval(myInterval);
}, 500);
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/beroxawudo/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: don't forget to `clearInterval` once you're done unless you want it to keep checking every 500ms for new `li` elements

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't add the class immediatly to the first li.

Comment: then just do a `$('#menu-offcanvas li:not(.myclass)').first().addClass('myclass');` at start before the `setInterval()` function

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval instead of Timeout and the .first() method, note code is untested

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){

  var firstLI = $('#menu-offcanvas li').first();

  if(firstLI){
    $('#menu-offcanvas li:not(.myclass)').first().addClass('myclass');
  }else{
    clearInterval(myVar)
  }

}, 500);
```

Comment: shouldnt it be `$('#menu-offcanvas li:not(.myclass)').first().addClass('myclass');`?

Comment: @cari can you post that as an answer. That actually worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

Building on Cari's answer:

```
// Define the scope and then run once:
var target = '#menu-offcanvas li:not(.myclass):first';
$(target).addClass('myclass');

// Set interval to run the same thing until there is no need to run any more:
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
    var item = $(target);
    item ? item.addClass('myclass') : window.clearInterval(myInterval);
}, 500);
```

We store the query as a string so that we can run it every interval. Alternatively, we could store the collection of list items and slice it every interval to save a little CPU power:

```
// Define the scope and then run once:
var $target = $('#menu-offcanvas li:not(.myclass)');
$target.first().addClass('myclass');

// Set interval to run the same thing until there is no need to run any more:
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
    // remove the first item
    $target = $target.slice(1);
    // if the collection's length is still true
    // add the class to the first item
    // else end the timer
    $target.length ? $target.first().addClass('myclass') : window.clearInterval(myInterval);
}, 500);
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zidolijife/1/edit?html,css,js,output)